# If values put into a CSV file with (For i)

Tags: vba, excel

My code isn't working, and i couldnt seem to find a solution in already asked questions.

I want to paste in data to the CSV file, but it doesnt seem to be able to find it.

It bugs at

outputFile.Cells(i, 2) = 1949.5 + (Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 5) / 2)

which is where i locate the data. Is anybody able to see what's wrong?

```
Sub works()

Dim outputFile          'Pointer to the file
Dim outputFileName      'Filename of the export file
Dim outputPath          'Path for the file

Dim numRows
Dim currentRow

Dim writeFile
Dim fileExists

writeFile = vbYes

outputFile = FreeFile
outputFileName = "AdminExport.csv"
outputPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

fileExists = Dir(outputPath & Application.PathSeparator & outputFileName)

If (fileExists <> "") Then
    writeFile = MsgBox("File already exists at the moment!" & vbCrLf & "Do you want to overwrite it with a new one?", vbYesNo + vbCritical)
End If

If (writeFile = vbYes) Then
    Open outputPath & Application.PathSeparator & outputFileName For Output Lock Write As #outputFile
    'Lock write = VBA har fuld rettighed til dokumentet (Ekslusivt)

    For i = 2 To 18288
        If Left(Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 12), 6) = "262015" Then
        outputFile.Cells(i, 2) = 1949.5 + (Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 5) / 2)
        End If
    Next i

    Print #outputFile, "Person_ID;STUDENT_ID_OLD;STUDENT_ID_NEW;ENROLL_PERIOD"
    'Overskrifter i CSV-filen

    numRows = Worksheets("Base").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    For currentRow = 2 To numRows
    'Tæller antal rækker i "Base"

    Print #outputFile, Worksheets("Base").Range("A" & currentRow) & ";" & Worksheets("Base").Range("B" & currentRow)


    Next
End If

Close outputFile
'Lukker den, da vi har 'open' oppe over





End Sub
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do the different parts of `Open outputPath & Application.PathSeparator & outputFileName For Output Lock Write As #outputFile` do, and do you know of anywhere I can read up on the syntax you have used here? My initial guess at your error is that your outputfile hasn't been set to a file-object, and / or that you can't use file.cells directly, but it is hard to say without being able to parse all the code. If you e.g. put a `Debug.Print outputFile.Name` before the line it bugs out on, what does that say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this part of the code in the line you're getting the error:

```
outputFile.Cells(i, 2)
```

You cannot reference cells the same way as in Excel when writing to binary files. You need to use the `print` statement instead for that. See [this](https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/vba-write-to-text-file-print-statement/) tutorial.